What is the best architecture for multi-target text regression?
I'm building an AI model using Google's 'Civil-Comments' dataset. It has 7 different labels, each a float than can be anywhere from 0 to 1. Embedding Bags, which I have read about. do not perform well. I've been looking into transformers and recurrent systems (LSTM, GRU, RNN, etc.). What should I do?
Using PyTorch, if it matters. But I'm not looking for code.
